# Selecting checked checkboxes out of multiple checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, checkbox

```
function getParam() {
    alert($("#paramNameVal").val());
    //  $paramName=$('#paramName');
    alert("Hi");
    var checkboxes;
    $("D1").change(function() {
        $("checkboxes").append("D1");
    });
    alert($("#checkboxes").val());
    var interval = document.getElementById('time').value;
    $("#showParam1").html("");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "dojo_Getgrid.action",
        data: {
            Interval: interval,
            Userlist: $("#paramNameVal").val(),
            checkID: checkboxes
        },
        // data: { ,},
        //data:$("#paramName").val(), 
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            alert(response);
            $("#showParam1").html(response);
            // document.getElementById("showParam").style.display='block';
        }
    });
}
```

Hello .what I am trying to do is that ,I have got 7 checkboxes on screen representing days of the week ,,and there is a save button on click of that button ,I want to send the id/name of  all those checkboxes which have been checked by user along with the ajax call to  the java class , so that I can know all the days for which user has checked the corresponding checkbox .

till now I have used .change function ,if value of that checkbox is changed then a constant representing id of checkbox is saved in variable names checkboxes and ultimatley send this variable checkboxes to java class along with ajax call

```
$("D1").change(function() {
    $("checkboxes").append("D1");
});
```

but when i used `alert($("#checkboxes").val());` to know ,what is ultimatley stored in that variable checkboxes ,it shows undefined as and alert ..

here is my JSP page :-

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html;  charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sjg" uri="/struts-jquery-grid-tags"%>
<head>
<title><s:label key="Master.Title" /></title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jscript/selectivizr-min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jscript/selectivizr.js"></script>

<sj:head debug="true" jqueryui="true" />

<s:set name="theme" value="'simple'" scope="page" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="JQuery/themes/start/jquery.ui.all.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="JQuery/custom.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/screens.css">
<%-- <script type="text/javascript" src="css/screens.js"></script> --%>
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="../JQuery/jquery.jqGrid-4.1.2/css/ui.jqgrid.css">
<script>

function addMore()
{
    //alert("addMore");
    var paramName=document.getElementById("descr_1").value;
     document.parameterGrid.action = "addNewParameter.action?descr="+paramName;
      document.parameterGrid.submit();
}
function activateParam()
{
    //alert("Activate Button");
    var size=document.getElementById('gridSize').value;
    //alert(size);

     var checkboxValue=0;
     for(var i=1; i<=size; i++) {
         //alert(document.getElementById("visible_"+i).checked);
            if(document.getElementById("visible_"+i).checked==true)
                {
                checkboxValue=1;
                }
     }
     if(checkboxValue == 0)
         {
         $('#reqId').html("<s:text name='alert.atleastoneval'/>");
            $('#alertToUser').dialog('open');
             return false;
         //alert("Please Select atleast one value"); 

         }

    for(var i=1; i<=size; i++) {

    //alert(document.getElementById("visible_"+i).checked);
    if(document.getElementById("visible_"+i).checked==true)
        {
        //alert("checked"+document.getElementById("paramVal_"+i));
        paramval=document.getElementById("paramVal_"+i).value;
        //alert(paramval);
        if(i!=1)
        paramid=paramval+','+paramid;
        else
            paramid=paramval;
        //alert(paramid);
        }
    }
    document.parameterGrid.action = "activateParameter.action?paramName="+paramid;
    document.parameterGrid.submit();
}


var paramid='';
var paramval=0;
function deactivateParam()
{
//alert("Dectivate Button");
    var size=document.getElementById('gridSize').value;
    //alert(size);

     var checkboxValue=0;
     for(var i=1; i<=size; i++) {
         //alert(document.getElementById("visible_"+i).checked);
            if(document.getElementById("visible_"+i).checked==true)
                {
                checkboxValue=1;
                }
     }
     if(checkboxValue == 0)
         {

         alert("<s:text name='alert.pleaseselectonevalue'/>"); 
         return false;
         }

    for(var i=1; i<=size; i++) {
 //alert(document.getElementById("visible_"+i).checked);
    if(document.getElementById("visible_"+i).checked==true)
        {
        //alert("checked"+document.getElementById("paramVal_"+i));
        paramval=document.getElementById("paramVal_"+i).value;
        //alert(paramval);
        if(i!=1)
        paramid=paramval+','+paramid;
        else
            paramid=paramval;
        //alert(paramid);
        }

    }


    document.parameterGrid.action = "deactivateParameter.action?paramName="+paramid;
    document.parameterGrid.submit();
   }
//For Displaying TimeSlots 
/* function getSlots()
{
    alert ("hi");
    var interval=document.getElementById('time').value;
alert(interval);
    $.ajax({  
          type: "POST",  
          url: "dojo_Getintervals.action",  
          // data: {paramName: $paramName.val() },
          data:{Interval:interval} ,
          success: function( response ) {
                console.log( response );
              // alert(response.finalSlots);
           //     $("#showParam").html(response);
           //     document.getElementById("showParam").style.display='block';
           var result=response.finalSlots;
           var $select = $('#t1');
            $select.find('option').remove();
            $('<option>').val('0').text('Select').appendTo($select);
            $.each(result, function(i, field) {
                $('<option>').val(i).text(field).appendTo($select);
            });
                document.parameterGrid.t1.disabled = false;
              }          
          });
} */
/* function gettoSlots()
{
    alert ("hi");
    var interval=document.getElementById('time').value;
    var screenval=$('#t1 option:selected').text();
    alert(screenval);
    $.ajax({  
          type: "POST",  
          url: "dojo_Gettovalue.action",  
          // data: {paramName: $paramName.val() },
          data:{Interval:interval , val: screenval} ,
          success: function( response ) {
                console.log( response );
              // alert(response.finalSlots);
           //     $("#showParam").html(response);
           //     document.getElementById("showParam").style.display='block';
           var result=response.toMap;
           var $select = $('#t2');
            $select.find('option').remove();
            $('<option>').val('0').text('Select').appendTo($select);
            $.each(result, function(i, field) {
                $('<option>').val(i).text(field).appendTo($select);
            });
                document.parameterGrid.t2.disabled = false;
              }          
          }); 
}*/
function check()
{


      for(var i=1; i<=7; i++) {

          if(document.getElementById("All").checked==true)
              {
              document.getElementById("D"+i).checked=true;
              }else
                document.getElementById("D"+i).checked=false;

         }

}
function getParam()
{
    alert ($("#paramNameVal").val());
    //  $paramName=$('#paramName');
    alert("Hi");
   var checkboxes; 
   $("D1").change(function(){
           $("checkboxes").append("D1");
     });
   alert($("#checkboxes").val());
    var interval=document.getElementById('time').value;
    $("#showParam1").html("");
    $.ajax({  
          type: "POST",  
          url: "dojo_Getgrid.action",  
          data:{Interval:interval ,Userlist : $("#paramNameVal").val(),checkID : checkboxes },
          // data: { ,},
          //data:$("#paramName").val(), 
          success: function( response ) {
                console.log( response );
                alert(response);
                $("#showParam1").html(response);
               // document.getElementById("showParam").style.display='block';
              }          
          });
}

</script>
<style>
.grid-view-table {
    width: 100%;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 12px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

.grid-view-table tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #ECF1F7;
    height: 23px;
}

.grid-view-table tr:nth-child(1) 
{
    background-color: #ECF1F7;
    height: 1px;
    text-align: center;
}
/* .grid-view-table tr:hover
{
    background: url("images/ui-bg_glass_75_79c9ec_1x400.png") repeat-x scroll 50% 50% rgb(121, 201, 236);
    border: 1px solid rgb(68, 141, 174);
    color: rgb(2, 104, 144);
    font-weight: normal;
} */
.grid-view-table .selected-row {
    background: url("images/ui-bg_glass_55_f8da4e_1x400.png") repeat-x
        scroll 50% 50% rgb(248, 218, 78);
    border: 1px solid rgb(252, 209, 19);
    color: rgb(145, 86, 8);
}
/*.grid-view-table tr th{
    background: url("images/ui-bg_gloss-wave_75_2191c0_500x100.png") repeat-x scroll 50% 50% rgb(33, 145, 192);
    border: 1px solid rgb(66, 151, 215);
    /*border: 1px solid black;*/
/* color: rgb(234, 245, 247);
    font-weight: bold;
}*/
.grid-view-table tr td {
    border: 1px solid rgb(166, 201, 226);
    padding: 1px 2px 1px 2px;
}
/*.grid-view-table tr:nth-child(2){
    background: url("images/ui-bg_glass_45_0078ae_1x400.png") repeat-x scroll 50% 50% rgb(0, 120, 174);
    border: 1px solid rgb(119, 213, 247);
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:bold;
}*/
.header-background {
    background: url("images/ui-bg_glass_45_0078ae_1x400.png") repeat-x
        scroll 50% 50% rgb(0, 120, 174);
    border: 0px solid rgb(119, 213, 247);
    /*border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #0078AE 50%, #006695 50%);*/
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "verdana";
}

/* above this is decorative, not part of the test */
.fixed-table-container {
    width: 99%;
    height: 240px;
    border: 1px solid #2A95C2;
    margin: 10px auto;
    background-color: white;
    /* above is decorative or flexible */
    position: relative; /* could be absolute or relative */
    padding-top: 20px; /* height of header */
    text-align: center;
}

.fixed-table-container-inner {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.header-background {
    height: 20px; /* height of header */
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.th-inner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    line-height: 20px; /* height of header */
    /*border-left: 1px solid black;*/
    font-family: verdana;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    font-size: 12px;
    width: 20%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<!-- <div class="fixed-table-container"></div> -->
        <!-- <div class="header-background"></div> -->
        <!--  <div class="fixed-table-container-inner">  -->

            <s:form name="parameterGrid" theme="simple" >
             <fieldset > 
             <table style=" margin: 0px;" border="0"
                        class="table-form">

                    <tr >
                            <td align="justify"><s:label key="Everyday"></s:label></td>
                            <td align="justify"><s:checkbox name="All" id="All" theme="simple" onclick="check();"></s:checkbox></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>        
                            <td ><s:label key="Sunday"></s:label></td>
                            <td ><s:checkbox name="D1" id="D1" theme="simple"></s:checkbox></td>
                            <td ><s:label key="Monday"></s:label></td>
                            <td ><s:checkbox name="D2" id="D2" theme="simple" ></s:checkbox></td>
                            <td><s:label key="Tuesday"></s:label></td>
                            <td ><s:checkbox name="D3" id="D3" theme="simple"></s:checkbox></td>
                            <td><s:label key="Wednesday"></s:label></td>
                            <td ><s:checkbox name="D4" id="D4" theme="simple"></s:checkbox></td>
                            <td><s:label key="Thursday"></s:label></td>
                            <td ><s:checkbox name="D5" id="D5" theme="simple"></s:checkbox></td>
                            <td><s:label key="Friday"></s:label></td>
                            <td ><s:checkbox name="D6" id="D6" theme="simple"></s:checkbox></td>
                            <td><s:label key="Saturday"></s:label></td>
                            <td ><s:checkbox name="D7" id="D7" theme="simple"></s:checkbox></td>


                        </tr>
                        </table>

             <table style=" margin: 0px;" border="0"
                         >          
                         <tr>
                         <s:hidden name="paramNameVal" id="paramNameVal" value="%{Users}" />
                        <td ><s:label key="Time Interval" /></td>
                            <td style="text-align: left;" ><s:select name="time" id="time"
                                    list="timeMap" listKey="value" listValue="key" headerKey=""
                                    headerValue="Select" maxlength="25" cssClass="selectbx" onchange="getSlots();" /></td>
                                    <%--  <td><s:label key="From" /></td> --%>
                    <%--        <td style="text-align: right;"><s:select name="t1" id="t1"
                                    list="finalSlots" listKey="key" listValue="value" headerKey=""
                                    headerValue="Select" maxlength="25" cssClass="selectbx" onchange="gettoSlots();" disabled="true"/></td>
                                     <td><s:label key="To" /></td>  
                            <td style="text-align: right;"><s:select name="t2" id="t2"
                                    list="toMap" listKey="key" listValue="value" headerKey=""
                                    headerValue="Select" maxlength="25" cssClass="selectbx" disabled="true"/></td> --%> 
                        <%--  <td> <s:label
                         key="Break"></s:label></td>
                         <td ><s:textfield name="employeeCode" id="employeeCode" maxlength="50" /></td> --%>

                        </tr>
            </table>
            <div align = "right">                       
                    <span id="addNew">  
                    <sj:a align="right" name="add" button="true" 
                                            cssClass="mediumBtn" 
                            formIds="dummy" id="add" onclick= "getParam();"><s:label key="Schedule" /></sj:a>    
                  </span>

          </div>

                    </fieldset>


                    <div id="showParam1"></div>
                <%-- <s:include value="/pages/TimeBound/timeboundGrid.jsp"></s:include> --%>




                    </s:form>



                    <!-- </div> -->

                    <br> 



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Whats `"D1"`? Is it ID or class name? and where it is? Show your HTML also.

Comment: actually It is id of checkbox ,but when i am using $("checkboxes").append("D1"); I simply want store string D1 in variable checkboxes ,,here I am not referring to id of checkbox

Comment: then you need to use `#D1` in `$("D1")`

Comment: actually this $("D1").change(function() piece of code is working ,,it checks if the value of checkbox is changed or not ,but I want thaoult if value of checkbox with id D1 is changed then a string 'D1' should be stored in variable checkboxes ,for eg .. if checkbox 1 = sunday ,checkbox 2 = monday ,checkbox 3 = tuesday is checked then variable checkboxes should contain= D1,D2,D3 .this should reach as string to java class ..Hope I have explained  better this time

Comment: Use tenary operator `$(selector).is(':checked')` it will return true if checked or false if unchecked, and then create function to check it, and return its value.

Answer (score 0):

You have no need to save value of checkbox to variable (in this case D1).
You can find selected checkbox when button clicked and send it to server by ajax like this

```
$('.submit').click(function(){
    var params = $('input:checked').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "...",
        data: params,
        success: function(response) {...}
    });
    return false;
});
```

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" value="D1" name="day" /> Sunday
<input type="checkbox" value="D2" name="day" /> Monday
<input type="checkbox" value="D3" name="day" /> Tuesday
...
```

and on server side, you can obtain data by using

```
String[] day = request.getParamterValues("day");
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply ,I appreciate your help .but I have to use <s:checked> tag in jsp ,,,not the basic HTML one ,so I can not use the type attribute ,therefore how can i serialize

Comment: You can use <s:checkbox name="day" fieldValue="D1" label="Sunday"/> instead of my HTML. It's same with my HTML

Comment: But how will I refer than in my case at the time of serializing  ,as you referred in your code - var params = $('input:checked').serialize(); by using input:checked .

Comment: no need to change. although you write <s:checkbox > in your code, but it will print <input > on browser.

Answer (score 0):

add this to your page :

```
<div id="checkboxes" style="display: none;"></div>
```

You can use class on your jsp, right? so you have to do this :

```
<s:checkbox name="D1" id="D1" class="checkBox" value="D1" theme="simple"></s:checkbox>
<s:checkbox name="D2" id="D2" class="checkBox" value="D2" theme="simple"></s:checkbox>
...
```

and now call it using jquery like this :

```
$( ".checkBox" ).change(function() {
    var $input = $( this );
    $("#checkboxes").append($input.attr('ID')); //change this
}
```

Jquery is checking every `.checkBox` for changes, and if it change jquery will append it values to `#checkboxes`

hope it will help, sorry for my english. :D

Comment: function getParam()
{
 alert ($("#paramNameVal").val());
 //  $paramName=$('#paramName');
    alert("Hi");
    var checkboxes ;  
   $( ".checkBox" ).change(function() {
    var $input = $( this );
    $("checkboxes").append($input.val());
}); I did exactly what you said ,,, but still the alert says undefined ,please help

Comment: can you show me your `<s:checkbox ... /s:checkbox>` source after you compile it?

Comment: sorry my friend ,but it still dont work ,,,i even tried using fieldalue attribute instead of value as well but nothing,the alert still pops ,but it shows nothing

Comment: try `.append($input.attr('ID'));`

Comment: $("#checkboxes").append($input.attr('ID').val); what about this

Comment: write this `alert($input.attr('id'));` after `var $input = $(this);` and tell me what you got ?

Comment: I didn't got any pop up for alert($input.attr('id'));